# Unable to configure own persistence layer

Tags: orbeon

I'm using Orbeon Forms 3.9 CE. To save the form data into a relational db, I decided to implement my own REST service. But now, when I tried to configure it in Orbeon, it doesn't worked.

I created the properties-local.xml in /WEB-INF/resources/config like this:

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

          <property as="xs:anyURI"
              name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.*"
              value="http://localhost:8090/orb-form-persistence/FormPersistence"/>
</properties>
```

After server restart, when I try to submit data to a form, Orbeon nevertheless uses eXist instead of my service.

Any tips for me? Thanks!

Comment: fnst, are you using the 3.9 release, or a nightly build? If the latter, this would explain why your configuration isn't working as the way the persistence layer is configured changed after 3.9 was was released.

Comment: @avernet, I'm using the stable 3.9 release. I've tried also the new configuration with defining an own provider, if you mean this. But it doesn't worked, too. Is there any configuration which overrides the `properties-local.xml`?

Comment: OK, in what app is your form? If you are using one of the sample app and form name (say `orbeon/bookshelf`), the more specific mapping defined in `properties-form-runner.xml` (you can see those mapping towards the end of https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/3.9-ce-stable/src/resources-packaged/config/properties-form-runner.xml) for those forms will take the precedence over the one your defined. Are you by any chance hitting that case?

Comment: Thank you, but I have no specified `properties-form-runner.xml`. After I created it, Orbeon seems to using eXist not longer. Now Orbeon tries to send a request to default `localhost:8080`. Is it helpful for you, if I post some logs?    |    _I've added to the 'XForms Hello' example some new fields and a save submission. With eXist it has worked very well._

Comment: It is normal you don't have a `properties-form-runner.xml` in your `config` directory. That file is one of the Orbeon Forms jar files, because you are not supposed to change it. Instead, you change `properties-local.xml`, and whatever properties you define there override the defaults defined in `properties-form-runner.xml`. The only interest for you to look at `properties-form-runner.xml` is to see what the default values are. But again, I recommend you don't copy that file in your `resources/config`.

Comment: Now, you are saying that Orbeon tries to connect to `localhost:8080`. What is the path after that? Is it the path to eXist (which you don't want) or the path to your persistence layer (`/orb-form-persistence/FormPersistence`) and it is just the port that is incorrect? You are still talking about Orbeon Forms not calling your persistence layer but instead storing data in eXist, right?

Comment: @avernet Yes, you're right. Orbeon Forms doesn't use my configuration for specific persistence layer.
After the `save-submission` this is logged: `DefaultClientConnectionOperator  - Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080` and `ConnPoolByRoute  - Getting free connection [HttpRoute[{}->http://localhost:8080]][null]`. So I guess my path (as mentioned above) isn't recognized at all.

Comment: I am wondering if this is because, somehow, your `properties-local.xml` is not at all taken into account. Could you try put an additional `<` character as the first character of the file, to make it invalid XML, and see if you get an error when loading a page? You should, as Orbeon Forms shouldn't be able to read it. (And if you don't get an error, this is a sign the file isn't read by Orbeon Forms.)

Comment: Okay, I think I've found my problem. But I'm a little bit confused though. I've just tried to save data with the 'bookshelf' form and it worked (Orbeon Forms has send a request to my REST service)! Before this, I always tried saving with the 'bookcast' example or my altered 'hello' example which both are using 'save-submissions'. Could you please explain me, what the difference between these is?

Comment: That explains it then: the persistence layer is used out of the box only by forms created with Form Builder. You could write forms in XForms that use that same persistence layer, but this isn't the case with the examples that ship with Orbeon Forms.

Comment: Thank you for your patient answers!

Comment: You're very welcome, and I also posted a summary in an answer below, so people having the same problem can spare spare themselves reading through our discussion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is correct, but it only applies to forms using the [Form Runner persistence layer](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api). While it is possible to use the Form Runner persistence layer with forms you write in XForms "by hand", typically it will only be used by the forms you create with [Form Builder](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/orbeon-form-builder).